# Simple java chat server that only broadcasts to other clients not sender

Tags: java

I have been working through a tutorial for a simple java chat server and would like to modify it so that it doesn't echo back to the original sender. I have tried to mod it with my limited skills but nothing I know has worked and any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashSet;


public class ChatServer {


// Port that the server listens on.
private static final int PORT = 9001;


// Creates names
private static HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();


// Creates writers
private static HashSet<PrintWriter> writers = new HashSet<PrintWriter>();

// Main method, which just listens on a port and spawns handler threads.
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("The Chatty server is running.");
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    try {
        while (true) {
            new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
        }
    } finally {
        listener.close();
    }
}


private static class Handler extends Thread {
    private String name;
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;


    public Handler(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }


    public void run() {
        try {

// Create character streams for the socket.
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

    // Request a name from this client.  Keep requesting until
    // a name is submitted that is not already used.  Note that
    // checking for the existence of a name and adding the name
            // must be done while locking the set of names.
            while (true) {
                out.println("SUBMITNAME");
                name = in.readLine();
                if (name == null) {
                    return;
                }
                synchronized (names) {
                    if (!names.contains(name)) {
                        names.add(name);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Now that a successful name has been chosen, add the
            // socket's print writer to the set of all writers so
            // this client can receive broadcast messages.
            out.println("NAMEACCEPTED");
            writers.add(out);

            // Accept messages from this client and broadcast them.
            // Ignore other clients that cannot be broadcasted to.
            while (true) {
                String input = in.readLine();
                if (input == null) {
                    return;
                }
// Where to add the section that prevents sending to original sender?
                for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
                    writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
                    System.out.println(writer);
                    System.out.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
                }
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            // This client is going down!  Remove its name and its print
            // writer from the sets, and close its socket.
            if (name != null) {
                names.remove(name);
            }
            if (out != null) {
                writers.remove(out);
            }
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the client

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class ChatClient {

BufferedReader in;
PrintWriter out;
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chatty");
JTextField textField = new JTextField(40);
JTextArea messageArea = new JTextArea(8, 40);

public ChatClient() {

// Layout GUI
    textField.setEditable(false);
    messageArea.setEditable(false);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField, "North");
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(messageArea), "Center");
    frame.pack();

// Add Listeners
    textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            out.println(textField.getText());
            textField.setText("");
        }
    });
}


// Prompt for and return the desired screen name.
private String getName() {
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
        frame,
        "Choose a screen name:",
        "Screen name selection",
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}


// Connects to the server then enters the processing loop.
    private void run() throws IOException {

    // Make connection and initialize streams
    String serverAddress = "0";
    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9001);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        socket.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

// Process all messages from server, according to the protocol.
    while (true) {
        String line = in.readLine();
        if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
            out.println(getName());
        } else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
            textField.setEditable(true);
        } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
            messageArea.append(line.substring(8) + "\n");
        }
    }
}


// Runs the client as an application with a closeable frame.

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
    client.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    client.frame.setVisible(true);
    client.run();
}
}
```

Comment: It's normal to echo back so the user knows their message has been received by the server.

Comment: Put client connections in a `Map<String, Connection>`, when you get a message send it to every one, but the matching name. As markspace points out, it is not unusual to send the message back to the client.

Comment: I am trying get a deeper understand of the mechanics what's occurring in the code and I thought this would be a simple control to add to the system.

Comment: By Map<String, Connection> are you referring to creating a hashmap?

Comment: Map is the interface: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html  HashMap (note capitalization) is one implementation of a Map https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: so you need to send back the data bt not to the original sender am i right

Comment: Yes, only to other clients not sender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ChatServer {


// Port that the server listens on.
private static final int PORT = 9001;


// Creates names
private static HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();


// Creates writers
private static HashMap<String,PrintWriter> writers = new HashMap<String,PrintWriter>();

// Main method, which just listens on a port and spawns handler threads.
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("The Chatty server is running.");
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    try {
        while (true) {
            new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
        }
    } finally {
        listener.close();
    }
}


private static class Handler extends Thread {
    private String name;
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;


    public Handler(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }


    public void run() {
        try {

// Create character streams for the socket.
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            String keyForEachUser =  socket.getInetAddress().toString();

    // Request a name from this client.  Keep requesting until
    // a name is submitted that is not already used.  Note that
    // checking for the existence of a name and adding the name
            // must be done while locking the set of names.
            while (true) {
                out.println("SUBMITNAME");
                name = in.readLine();
                if (name == null) {
                    return;
                }
                synchronized (names) {
                    if (!names.contains(name)) {
                        names.add(name);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Now that a successful name has been chosen, add the
            // socket's print writer to the set of all writers so
            // this client can receive broadcast messages.
            out.println("NAMEACCEPTED");
            writers.put(keyForEachUser,out);

            // Accept messages from this client and broadcast them.
            // Ignore other clients that cannot be broadcasted to.
            while (true) {
                String input = in.readLine();
                if (input == null) {
                    return;
                }
// Where to add the section that prevents sending to original sender?

                for (String key : writers.keySet()) {
                        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(keyForEachUser)) {
                        //original user founf not sending the data
                        }else{
                        PrintWriter writer = writers.get(key); //getting the correct output stream
                        writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
                        System.out.println(writer);
                        System.out.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
                        }
                }

                }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            // This client is going down!  Remove its name and its print
            // writer from the sets, and close its socket.
            if (name != null) {
                names.remove(name);
            }
            if (out != null) {
                writers.remove(out);
            }
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

i have made some changes to your program , problem with your earlier code was that you cant identify users connected. now im using a hashmap object to store the printwriters and the key im using in hashmap is users inetaddress which is unique from pc to pc. maybe you should try this one

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. The clients are running are running on the same computer.

Comment: you got any errors or you got the previous outputs , try running only one single client since you have only one computer ,

Comment: No output on single or multiple clients. Compiles with no errors. A single client would not give any output if functioning properly, so I need two clients running on the same computer to test the function, so net address probably will not work as a key.

Comment: Checked the netaddress portion and all clients look like they have the same ip.

Comment: Would it be easier to use an array or array list to store the values and use the "name" variable as the reference for the  if then in the broadcast loop?

Comment: not getting an output is a good thing , my code is working , and how come you have multiple clients on the same computer you can have them bt there is no way to distinguish between them except for the ip. thats the only key . request from same computer wont act as seperate requests..

Comment: Had a chance to try it out using multiple computer and I am happy to say it does work. Thanks for your help. It is greatly appreciated.